# Changing the Shell registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry, windows-shell, regedit

At the start of my application i change the shell value of the registry to a custom shell and kill the explorer.exe (It is done outside the application), i want to allow a backdoor to return to the original shell and bring back the explorer.exe. brining the process back works fine for me but when i run my code to change the registry value no exception is thrown but the value doesn't change when i check in regedit,
this is my code (saw it here on a different question) :

```
        RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
        regKey.SetValue("Shell", "explorer.exe", RegistryValueKind.String);
        regKey.Close();
```

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code, you are actually set the value of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

Because some registry keys are redirected by WOW64, please check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get more details.

Try this:

```
RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

RegistryKey regKey = localMachine .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
regKey.SetValue("Shell", "explorer.exe", RegistryValueKind.String);
regKey.Close();
```