# Cannot change registry variable C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm in the middle of creating my own kiosk using C#, and for that I'm going to kill explorer (windows shell) and I don't need it to autorestart. For that cause I need to change one variable in the registry however, when I'm trying to run it from the IDE it gives me an error:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException:Access to the registry key %KEYPATH% is denied.

If I try to run the executable as an administrator, I get no error messages but nothing changes, variable is still set to "1". 
I also edited the permissions for that branch in registry for current user and even everyone, giving full access to that branch in the registry. This is the C# code I have

```
RegistryKey explorerAutoRestart;
string ear_keypath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon";

//GETTING ACCESS ERROR HERE
explorerAutoRestart = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ear_keypath); 
switch (status)
{
    case "0":
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon");
        key.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 0x00000000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        key.Close();
        break;

    case "1":
        explorerAutoRestart.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        explorerAutoRestart.Close();
        break;
}
```

I would like to know what's causing this issue and how do I change the value of
AutoRestartShell - REG_DWORD

Changing CreateSUbKey to OpenSubKey(path, true) only changed the error to
 Requested registry access is not allowed.

Perhaps Windows doesn't allow external editing for that branch?

Comment: Does "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" already exist? If not does any part of "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" NOT exist? Also where is `status` set?

Comment: FWIW, [kiosk mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-device-for-anyone-to-use) is an option in Windows 10.

Comment: First of all OpenSubKey function only gives me read-only access. No matter the permissions. Second of all I need my custom kiosk, for various reasons. I'm planning to replace the shell entirely later on. Window 10 kiosk mode doesn't allow me to have my custom windows form with MD5 hash protected password along with other custom functionality I'm writing, nonetheless I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: status is set elsewhere, obviously there's a bigger code, I'm only showing the main part that has problems. For example I'm also doing things here  @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System";

Comment: status variable comes in handy as I pass it in here  disableTaskMgr.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", status);

Comment: Nevermind, I've double checked and actually I have to pass an extra boolean if I want read-write with OpenSubKey. Nonetheless, nothing changed... Expect for a different error. Requested registry access is not allow. ROFL

Answer (score 3):

Managed to solve this issue. Apparently my keys were redirected by WOW64 and that somehow didn't give me permission to the registry branch?
Nonetheless following code saved me:

```
RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
            RegistryKey regKey = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
                    regKey.SetValue("Shell", "bat.exe", RegistryValueKind.String);
                    regKey.Close();
```

[Changing the Shell registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667287/changing-the-shell-registry)